# How to block ips with .htacces

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, request, ip, block

I need to block certain ip addresses on my website preferably with .htaccess methods. Can someone help me?   I request that i be given some sort of URL or code examples here thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`deny from ip_address` should work

Edit: add link http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-ip-address/

Answer (score 1):

> I need to block certain ip addresses on my website preferably with
>   .htaccess methods.

You can indicate which addresses you wish to block using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}`.

**Working Example:**

```
# BLOCK VISITORS REFERRED FROM GOOGLE.COM

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([a-z0-9-]+\.)?google\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

---

The example above uses a regular expression, so it will block:

- `https://` or `http://`
- followed by any subdomain (or none)
- followed by `google.com`
- followed by anything (or nothing)

---

The `[F]` flag means `Forbidden`. The server will return a `403 Forbidden Error`.